# Calculate scroll for showing in proportion on custom bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a custom horizontal scroll component that needs to calculate the whole scroll in proportion to the content block, that the scroll indication is always moving in proportion to the box so that the beginning of the scroll is when the first content element is on top of the view and reaches the end when the last content element is visible.

I made a pen mockup here, that shows the code
https://codepen.io/baxgas/pen/ExZOMqz

I think this part  is  not calculating correctly, but don't know the best solution, that, of course, works well with different sizes of viewports and content sizes

```
  const scrolldistance = (scrollcheck / diverLength) * 10;
```

That is giving the size here

```
  if (scrollcheck > distancefromStart) {
    $progressing.css("padding-top", Math.round(scrolldistance));
  }
```

Comment: i dont understant what is your problem....and what is the result waited?

Comment: As you can see from the codepen mockup, the calculator doesn't calculate correctly the scroll distance, it gets too early to the bottom. I would like to have the scroll distance calculation more evenly through the whole scroll height between the bottom of the first circle to the top of the last circle.